# Compare two excel files for the difference using pandas with multiple tabs

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I found this nice script online which does a great job comparing the differences between 2 excel sheets but there's an issue - it doesn't work if the excel files have multiple sheets in a given .xlsx:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_excel('file1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('file2.xlsx')

df1.equals(df2)

comparison_values = df1.values == df2.values

print(comparison_values)

rows, cols = np.where(comparison_values == False)
for item in zip(rows,cols):
    df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]] = '{} --> {}'.format(df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]], df2.iloc[item[0], item[1]])

df1.to_excel('./Excel_diff.xlsx', index = False, header = True)
```

It works really well for what I need it for except it does not work when I have multiple sheets in each .xlsx - it only compares the first sheet of the files. Any ideas how to alter the script above so that it compares all sheets in the file? Thanks

Comment: You can use `sheet_name=None` to load all sheets, but this will load the Excel file into a dictionary as `{'Sheet1': df1, 'Sheet2': df2, ...}`, so your script with need to take that into account, probably by looping through the dictionaries. Also, maybe look into using pandas' [compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html) method for getting the differences and [ExcelWriter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) to write multiple sheets for your output.

Answer (score 1):

As @StevenS said the comment section, you can use the `sheet_name=None` option to get a dictionary containing all of the sheets and dataframes from the input files. Then you need to decide how you want to distinguish each sheet in your output file. In the example below I put one sheet in the output diff file for each sheet found in the file1.xlsx input.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_excel('file1.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
df2 = pd.read_excel('file2.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

with ExcelWriter('./Excel_diff.xlsx') as writer:
    for sheet,df1 in xl_1.items():
        # check if sheet is in the other Excel file
        if sheet in xl_2:
            df2 = xl_2[sheet]
            comparison_values = df1.values == df2.values
            
            print(comparison_values)
            
            rows, cols = np.where(comparison_values == False)
            for item in zip(rows,cols):
                df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]] = '{} --> {}'.format(df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]], df2.iloc[item[0], item[1]])

            df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, index=False, header=True)
```

Comment: Thank you I'll check this out!

Comment: Thanks, if this solution ends up working out for you, please mark the question as answered. However, if it doesn't please send me a comment as to why not.